# Magento project redirecting to installation page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

I have magento 2.17 project which is working fine. I just created a copy of this project and then updated its env.xml with my new database details. But unfortunately when I'm accessing the project it redirect to the installation page.
Actually the project is already created and I have created a new database with data (the new database is imported from the original project). So I need to use this database and skip the installation process. Please let me know how to solve this issue.
these things are I already checked:

- deleted files from var/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove app/setup folder.
But i doubt that will help, because when you installing magento 2 it records all it's URLs into database.